# What is wrong with this SQL query?

Tags: sql

I'm getting a SQLException was unhandled by user code "Incorrect syntax near 'TBL'." I also tried to replace [PrioContextDb].[dbo].[RatingListTriangleModels] with just the table name and without brackets.

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
                    ("delete from [PrioContextDb].[dbo].[RatingListTriangleModels] TBL where ( TBL.To1Id = @MY_ID and TBL.To2Id = @OTHER_ID ) or ( TBL.To2Id = @My_ID and TBL.To3Id = @OTHER_ID ) or ( TBL.To3Id = @My_ID and TBL.To1Id = @OTHER_ID )", cn))
                {
                    //
                    // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
                    //
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("MY_ID", myToid));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("OTHER_ID", theirTradeObjectid));
                    var no = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the alias `TBL` after the `DELETE` keywrod like so:

```
delete TBL 
from [PrioContextDb].[dbo].[RatingListTriangleModels] TBL 
where ...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, you need to remove `TBL` to your SQL statement.  You'll need to remove it from all of your clauses too.

But it also looks like you are missing the `@` from your parameters which may be the next error that you get.

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MY_ID", myToid));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OTHER_ID", theirTradeObjectid));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try by removing the alias name TBL.

```
delete from [PrioContextDb].[dbo].[RatingListTriangleModels] 
where ( To1Id = @MY_ID and To2Id = @OTHER_ID ) or 
  ( To2Id = @My_ID and To3Id = @OTHER_ID ) or 
  ( To3Id = @My_ID and To1Id = @OTHER_ID )
```